# Intel De2i-FPGA board PCI

Tags: intel, fpga, pci, pci-e

Hi I have a FPGA board as the title suggests. I want to hook up 2 PCI cards to it. The block diagram of the board says it has two PCIe ports, however the picture of the board does not contain one. The manual of the FPGA mentions PCIe but the board simply does not have one. Other I/O include USB, RS-232, and SATA. Is there any possible way for me to hook up two PCI cards to the board using some kind of adapter or converter? Here is a link to the block diagram and picture. http://www.systemseng.cornell.edu/intel/team/upload/DE2i-150.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board has only one mPCIe connector, but the FPGA is using 2 PCIe channels to connect to the CPU chipset.

You should check out the HSMC connector to see if the PCIe signals are available then but I doubt it.

Comment: SO it looks like it's not possible. Thanks though!